# How can i make a .vbs or .bat file spam a photo?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, notepad

how can i make a file that will play a sound and spam the user with multiple pop ups?
i want for example the file to start playing a song like "never gonna give you up" and i setting a photo of rick astley face to spam the user who opens the file with his face, is that even possible? please share your code if you know the way.
i have no experience with .bat or .vbs, what i know its very little.
That is the code i was trying to write, just testing to see if i can play the spam image like when you type just start or start link and it starts the web browser and redirects you to that link.

```
@echo off
start D:\Vladimir\Desktop\New folder\5 Minutes Countdown by Free Video Contents.mp4
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its intent is malicious. It is also off topic because this is not a code request service, it only assists you to fix a reproducible issue with your own code, _which incidentally is lacking doublequotes_.

Answer (score 1):

This is inspired from [PowerShell Fun: Watch Rick Astley Sing and Dance Never Let You Down](https://www.nextofwindows.com/powershell-fun-watch-rick-astley-sing-and-dance-never-let-you-down)

***Decription:***

> Lee Holmes, the author of the popular “Windows PowerShell Cookbook”,
> has made a little fun project for April Fool’s day (not sure in which
> year) that turns Rick Astley to Risk ASCII and made him to dance and
> sing one of his popular songs, Never Let You Down, right inside your
> PowerShell screen.

You can give a try for this batch file :

```
@echo off
REM https://www.nextofwindows.com/powershell-fun-watch-rick-astley-sing-and-dance-never-let-you-down
REM ***************************************************************************************************************************
REM                                              Description in English :
REM ***************************************************************************************************************************
REM Never Gonna Give You Up is a song by singer Rick Astley from his first album Whenever You Need Somebody (1987).
REM His clip became the basis of an Internet phenomenon in the early 2000s, the rickroll.
REM ***************************************************************************************************************************
REM                                             Description en Français :
REM ***************************************************************************************************************************
REM Never Gonna Give You Up est une chanson du chanteur Rick Astley tiré de son premier album Whenever You Need Somebody (1987).
REM Son clip est devenu la base d'un phénomène Internet au début des années 2000, le rickroll.
REM ***************************************************************************************************************************
Mode 84,43
Title Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up With Powershell and Batch (1987-2020^)
Powershell ^
Invoke-Expression -Command (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.leeholmes.com/projects/ps_html5/Invoke-PSHtml5.ps1' -UseBasicParsing^).Content
```

---

[image]

Comment: it's Fascinating!!!